# Generated integers to a binary file

Tags: java

I have assignment question I could not get the final answer.

the question was :
 **Write a program that will write 100 randomly generated 
integers to a binary file using the writeInt(int) method in 
DataOutputStream. Close the file. Open the file using a 
DataInputStream and a BufferedInputStream. Read the integer 
values as if the file contained an unspecified number (ignore 
the fact that you wrote the file) and report the sum and average 
of the numbers.**

I believe I done first part of the question which is (write into file), but I don't know how to report the sum.

so far that what I have

```
import java.io.*;

public class CreateBinaryIO {
public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myData.dat"));
    int numOfRec = 0 + (int)(Math.random()* (100 - 0 +1));
    int[] counts = new int[100];
    for(int i=0;i<=100;i++){
        output.writeInt(numOfRec);      
        counts[i] += numOfRec;
    }// Loop i closed
    output.close();
}

}
```

This ReadBinaryIO class:

```
import java.io.*;


public class ReadBinaryIO {
    public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException {
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream (new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("myData.dat")));

        int value = input.readInt();

        System.out.println(value + " ");
        input.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, loop through the file until not `int`s are left and while looping, add them all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int numOfRec = 0 + (int)(Math.random()* (100 - 0 +1));
```

That's not generating a random number.  Look into `java.util.Random.nextInt()`.

```
int[] counts = new int[100];
for(int i=0;i<=100;i++){
   output.writeInt(numOfRec);      
   counts[i] += numOfRec;
}// Loop i closed
```

That wil actually break because you are using `i<=100` instead of just `i<100` but I'm not sure why you are populating that array to begin with? Also, that code just writes the same number 101 times.  The generation of that random number needs to be within the loop so a new one is generated each time.

As far as reading it back, you can loop through your file by using a loop like this:

```
long total = 0;
while (dataInput.available() > 0) {
  total += dataInput.readInt();
}
```

Comment: That was very helpful, Thank you guys ... I  followed your notice and I believe I did the assignment correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to divide the problem in parts to organice your code, don't forget to flush the OutputStream before you close it.

```
package javarandomio;


import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Random;

public class JavaRandomIO {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    writeFile();
    readFile();
}

private static void writeFile() {
    DataOutputStream output=null;
    try {
        output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myData.txt"));
        Random rn = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            output.writeInt(rn.nextInt(100));
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally{
        try{
            output.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private static void readFile() {
    DataInputStream input=null;
    try {
        input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("myData.txt"));
        int cont = 0;
        int number = input.readInt();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("cont =" + cont + " number =" + number);
            if (input.available() == 4) {
                break;
            }
            number = input.readInt();
            cont++;
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally{
        try{
            input.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you break when `input.available == 4` this will cause the last integer to be skipped. You should loop `while (input.available() > 0) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code where you are trying to read one integer:

```
   DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream (new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("myData.dat")));

   int sum = 0;
   for(int i =0; i<=100; i++){
        int value = input.readInt();
        sum += value;
    }

    System.out.println(value + " ");
    input.close();
```

Or if you want to dynamically set the lenght of the for loop then

create a File object on myData.dat file and then divide the size of file with 32bits

```
   File file = new File("myData.dat");
   int length = file.length() / 32;

   for(int i =0; i <= length;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I submit the assignment and I think I got.

```
/** Munti ... Sha
course code (1047W13), assignment 5 , question 1 , 25/03/2013, 

 This file read the integer values as if the file contained an unspecified number (ignore 
the fact that you wrote the file) and report the sum and average of the numbers.
*/

import java.io.*;
public class ReadBinaryIO {
    public static void main(String [] args)throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        //call the file to read 
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream (new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("myData.dat")));
        // total to count the numbers, count to count loops process
        long total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println("generator 100 numbers are ");
        while (input.available() > 0) {
          total += input.readInt();
          count ++;
            System.out.println(input.readInt());

        }
        //print the sum and the average
        System.out.println("The sum is " + total);
        System.out.println("The average is " + total/count);

        input.close();

    }

}
```

CreateBinaryIO Class:

> import java.io.*; import java.util.Random;
>
> public class CreateBinaryIO {         //Create a binary file public static
>   void main(String [] args)throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
>     DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new
>   FileOutputStream("myData.dat"));
>       Random randomno = new Random();
>
> ```
> for(int i=0;i<100;i++){       output.writeInt(randomno.nextInt(100));     }// Loop i closed   output.close(); }    }
> ```